# C# Regex Ignore trailing characters

Tags: c#, regex

I'm working with Regex's in C# and have not been able to find this example that I am looking for. I have a string that is structured as follows

```
string arg = "Type / Subtype: 001 / 002 Additional pointless information that we don't need"
```

Essentially what I am wondering is how can I format a Regex in C# to obtain the two number in this string. The addnitional information at the end is dynamic, so I cannot hardcode that information.

So what I have as if now is this:

```
Regex r = @Type / SubType: (\d+) / (\d+) ";
```

But I have no idea what to put at the end to ignore the trailing characters, any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to put anything. Regex allows partial matches of the given string (unless you specify anchors such as `^` and `$`).

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^Type / Subtype: (\d+) / (\d+)");
string arg = "Type / Subtype: 001 / 002 Additional pointless information that we don't need";
Match match = r.Match(arg);
if (match.Success)
{
    string num1 = match.Groups[1].Value;    // "001"
    string num2 = match.Groups[2].Value;    // "002"
}
```

One thing to watch out for: `"SubType"` is spelt using CamelCase in your pattern, but as `"Subtype"` in your string, so the regex won't match if it's case-sensitive (which is the default).

**Edit**: To match the final string as well, just add a parenthesized wildcard:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^Type / Subtype: (\d+) / (\d+) (.*)");
// ...
string remainder = match.Groups[3].Value;
```

Note that the preceding space is mandatory, and that `.` does not match newlines (unless you use the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option).

Comment: Thank you for this! It worked perfectly. Is there a way to match the final string as a group as well?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a lookahead or non-capturing group for the prefix:

```
(?<=Type / Subtype: )(\d+)(?: / )(\d+)
```

Now you'll have your two numbers in only two captured groups (`$1` and `$2` or however c# works) and `Type / Subtype:` will not consume the match.